# How to include a folder from another repo in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Task: Access the files of a folder from repo A inside repo B.

I checked the include keyword in GitLab but that is used only for .yml files.
I want to read the contents of a folder in repo B after it is imported from repo A.

Is there any way to do it using the .yml file?

Answer (score 2):

I think the only way to include a folder of another git repository is using a git [submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).
You can add a submodule with the command:

```
git submodule add -b <branch> git@<repo-B> path/where/to/add/repo-B
```

Then it's necessary to add the following variable in the job that requires the folder:

```yaml
myjob:
  variables:
    GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
```